# Why is async code considered so much faster than synchronous?

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous

Why is synchronous code considered so much slower and more resource intensive than asynchronous code? For example nginx is considered faster than Apache and a NodeJS application is considered faster than a PHP application.

Shouldn't it be trivial to compile synchronous code into an asynchronous equivalent? At least in JavaScript many people use libraries like [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) which help to write synchronous looking code.

**Edit**: Because of a question in the comments: Synchronous code like

```
byte[] buf = read(socket);
do_something(buf);
```

is considered slow because the thread has to block for reading from `socket`, whereas

```
read(socket, function(buf) {
    do_something(buf);
});
```

is considered fast. On the one hand the transformation should be trivial on the other hand both code has to wait for `read` just one time the thread has to be yielded whereas in the other case a return to the main event loop is necessary

Comment: Because asynchronous code does not have to wait for blocking resources unlike synchronous

Comment: It really depends on the code in question

Comment: @CodingDefined but that's what I said: It should be trivial to compile `byte[] buf = read(sock)` to `read(sock, function(buf) {})` so writing sync code compiled to async should be equally fast

Comment: @ooxi I'm confused what you're actually asking.  Is your question regarding runtime performance or how long it takes to write the code?

Comment: @Tom I'm asking why people bother writing code in async style (taking much longer to produce) while it should be automatically transferable from synchronous writing into asynchronous execution. But somehow it is not and I don't get why

Comment: "should be automatically transferable from synchronous writing into asynchronous execution" - What do you mean by this? Do you think the interpreter should automatically convert sync code into async, when it's written synchronously?

Comment: @ooxi Synchronous means that if you have to read five files it will read one after the other, whereas in asynchronous almost all the files start together...reading one file is synchronous because it has to read the file line by line...

Comment: @Tom yes exactly, and whether it's an interpreter or the compiler should not matter. CodingDefined I took your example and compiled it from sync to async http://pastebin.com/fgq2ELTd. The rules for doing so should be clear and I don't get where the edge cases are where an automatic transformation is not possible anymore

Comment: @ooxi How would it know an operation needs to be async?  The interpreter would have to have overhead to check if a sync operation could be async, then transform it, then workout if there's a callback etc.  It's trivial for a developer to code it, and there may be instances where you may not want an operation to be async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asynchronous/non-blocking designs are not necessarily faster, but they can scale better than synchronous/blocking designs under some circumstances.  Thus, they can be "faster" when handling high volumes of parallel transactions.

There are two primary reasons for the performance differences between the two approaches.  One reason is the overhead of thread context switching, the other is the memory consumption of threads on some platforms (e.g. Java)

[I recently completed an article that explains why asynchronous can scale better.](http://monztech.com/index.php/2015/10/08/blocking-vs-nonblocking-io-whats-going-on/)  I hope it is helpful.

Comment: the link to the article returns a 403 error and wayback machine says that previous versions cannot be displayed because of your robots.txt